# How to draw flowchart in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I need to make this flowchart in LaTeX. I used the TikZ package but I don't know how to draw this parenthesis and this form. I also don't know why the arrows between the two last nodes aren't drawn.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    
    \usepackage[left=1.27cm,right=1.27cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
    % Required packages
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
    \definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
    \definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
    \definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
    \definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
    \definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}
    
    \definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}
    
    \begin{document}
     
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,thick]
     
         
    
    % Start block
    \node[draw, text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue1,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm] (block1) {ETAPES};
      
        \node[draw,
            right =of block1,
        minimum width=4cm,fill=yellow1,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm] (block2) {DOCUMENTS};
        \node[draw,
        left =of block1,rounded corners,
        minimum width=4cm,fill=gray1,
        minimum height=1cm] (block3) {ACTEURS};
    %ETAPE 2
    \node[draw,
        below=of block1,
         text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=orange1,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block4) { Remarque / Déficience };
     
     \node[draw,
        below  =of block3,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=gray2,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block5) {  Client };
    %ETAPE 3
    \node[draw,
        below=of block4,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
         text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block6) { Enregistrement de la remarque };
     
     \node[draw,
        below  = 2 cm of block5,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=gray2,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block7) {Responsable qualité  };
     \node[draw,
        below  =of block2,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow1,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block8) { BDD\_RETOUR\_INFOS\_CLIENTS };
    %ETAPE start
    \node[draw,
        below=of block6,
         text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block9) { Accusé-Réception de la remarque par mail  };
    
    \node[draw,
        below=of block9,
         text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=2cm
    ] (block10) { Définition d’un plan d’action si nécessaire : ouverture de CAPA };
    
    \node[draw,
        below=of block10,
         text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1.5cm
    ] (block11) { Communication des résultats d’analyse au client  };
    
    \node[draw,
        below=of block11,
        minimum width=5cm,text centered,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block12) {  Mise en œuvre et suivi du plan d’action };
     \node[draw,
        below=of block12,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        maximum  width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=2cm
    ] (block19) { Communication (au client) des résultats des actions entreprises et prise en compte de ses remarques };
     %ETAPE acteur 
    \node[draw,
        left =of block10,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=gray2,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block13) { Equipe + Responsable qualité  };
     \node[draw,
        below=3.5cm of block13,fill=gray2,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block14) { Responsable qualité  };
    %ETAPE DOCUMENTS
    \node[draw,
       right=of block10,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow1,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block15) { INS\_PLAN\_ACTION };
    \node[draw,
        right=of block12,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow1,
        minimum height=1cm
    ] (block16) { INS\_PLAN\_ACTION  };
    \node[coordinate,left=1.35cm of block14] (block20) {};
     \node[coordinate,left=1.35cm of block7] (block21) {};
     % Arrows
      
    \draw[-latex] (block1) edge (block4)
        (block4) edge (block6)
        (block6) edge (block9);
        \draw[-latex] 
           (block9) edge (block10);
           \draw[-latex] 
           (block10) edge (block11);
(block11) edge (block12);
(block12) edge (block19);
    
    % Arrows
    
    
     
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
     
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is extremely redundant, you should learn how to define styles to apply to several nodes, if not all. For your arrow issue, it happens taht you added semicolon after `\draw[-latex] (block10) edge (block11)`. Get rid of those semicolons. In order to draw on the side of the flow chart, you have to name your nodes and use those names to draw the braces. Plus, you wrote `maximum width` which doesn't exist.

Comment: And the shape you're looking for is `tape, tape bend top=none`, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit (1):**

- Now MWE reproduce image which you show in your answer.
- Since your answer is stated that it contain final code, I wonder, if you still interested for any other answer?
- Anyway, in MWE below are in comparison to your codes done the following changes:

  - node shapes have common style definition
  - nodes in main branch are organized in chain (by use `chains` library and use `join=by ...` macro for arrows between nodes

**Edit (2):**
Now I see that I show only desired image, but not MWE, Which rposuce it. Now is corrected
Complete MWE (for those who are interested) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.27cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

% Required packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning,
                shapes}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
\definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
\definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}

\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=3mm, width=6mm]}, line width= 2mm,
                 draw=blue2, shorten > = 1mm, shorten <=1mm},
  base/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum height=12mm, text width=44mm,
                 align=flush center},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour={#3} },
     M/.style = {base, fill=#1,
                 tape, 
                 tape bend top=none, tape bend height=2mm, tape bend bottom=in and out},
     N/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=#1}
                        ]
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr},
                  N/.default=blue2]
\node [N=blue1]     {ETAPES};                   % A-1
\node [N=orange1]   {Remarque / Déficience};    % A-2
\node [N]   {Enregistrement de la remarque};
\node [N]   {Accusé-Réception de la remarque par mail};
\node [N]   {Définition d’un plan d’action si nécessaire: ouverture de CAPA};
\node [N]   {Communication des résultats d’analyse au client};
\node [N]   {Mise en œuvre et suivi du plan d’action};
\node [N]   {Communication (au client) des résultats des actions entreprises et prise en compte de ses remarques};
\node [N]   {Réponse aux questions complémentaires par mail et téléphone};
    \end{scope}
% nodes on the left side of the main branch
\node [N=gray1,
       left=of A-1]     (B-1)   {ACTEURS};
\coordinate (aux1) at ($(A-3.south west)!0.5!(A-4.north west)$);
\node [N=gray2,
      left=of aux1]     (B-2)   {Client};
\node [N=gray1,
       left=of A-5]     (B-2)   {Responsable qualité};
\draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray]   (A-3.west) -- (A-4.west);

\coordinate (aux2) at ($(A-6.west)!0.5!(A-9.west)$);
\node [N=gray1,
      left=of aux2]     (B-3)   {Client};
\draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray]   (A-6.west) -- (A-9.west);
% nodes on the right side of thr main branch
    \begin{scope}[M/.default=yellow1]
\node[N=yellow1, 
         right=of A-1]      (C-1)   {DOCUMENTS};
\node[M, text width=55mm,
         at={(C-1 |- A-3)}] (C-2)   {BDD\_RETOUR\_INFOS\_CLIENTS};
\node[M, right=of A-5]      (C-3)   {INS\_PLAN\_ACTION};
\node[M, right=of A-7]      (C-4)   {INS\_PLAN\_ACTION};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
this is the final code 


   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.27cm,right=1.27cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
% Required packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
\definecolor{blue3}{RGB}{0,176,240}
\definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
\definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}
\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,thick]
        
        % Start block
        %ETAPE start
        
        \node[draw, text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue1,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm] (block1) {\textbf{ETAPES}};
        \node[draw,
        below=0.5cm of block1,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=orange1,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block4) { Remarque / Déficience };
        \node[draw,
        below=of block4,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block6) { Enregistrement de la remarque };
        
        \node[draw,
        below=of block6,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block9) { Accusé-Réception de la remarque par mail  };
        
        \node[draw,
        below=of block9,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=2cm
        ] (block10) { Définition d’un plan d’action si nécessaire : ouverture de CAPA };
        
        \node[draw,
        below=of block10,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1.5cm
        ] (block11) { Communication des résultats d’analyse au client  };
        
        \node[draw,
        below=of block11,
        minimum width=5cm,text centered,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block12) {  Mise en œuvre et suivi du plan d’action };
        \node[draw,
        below=of block12,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum  width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=2cm] (block19) { Communication (au client) des résultats des actions entreprises et prise en compte de ses remarques };
        \node[draw,
        below=of block19,
        text width=6cm ,text centered,
        minimum  width=5cm,fill=blue2,rounded corners,
        minimum height=2cm] (blockf) { Réponse aux questions complémentaires par mail et téléphone   };
        %ETAPE acteur 
        
        \node[draw,
        left =of block1,rounded corners,
        minimum width=4cm,fill=gray1,
        minimum height=1cm] (block3) {\textbf{ACTEURS}};
        
        \node[draw,
        below  =0.5of block3,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=gray2,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block5) {  Client };
        \node[draw,
        below  = 2 cm of block5,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=gray2,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block7) {Responsable qualité  };
        
        \node[draw,
        left =of block10,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=gray2,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block13) { Equipe + Responsable qualité  };
        \node[draw,
        below  = 5.7cm of block13,fill=gray2,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm
        ] (block14) { Responsable qualité  };
        %ETAPE DOCUMENTS
        \node[draw,
        right =2cm of block1,
        minimum width=4cm,fill=yellow1,rounded corners,
        minimum height=1cm] (block2) {\textbf{DOCUMENTS}};
        
        \node[draw,
        right=1.5cm of block6,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow1,tape, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=2mm,   tape bend bottom=in and out,
        minimum height=2cm
        ] (block8) { BDD\_RETOUR\_INFOS\_CLIENTS };
        \node[draw,
        right=2cm of block10,text width=4cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow1,tape, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=2mm,   tape bend bottom=in and out,
        minimum height=2cm
        ] (block15) { INS\_PLAN\_ACTION };
        \node[draw,
        right=2.2cm of block12, text width=4cm ,text centered,
        minimum width=3cm,fill=yellow1,tape, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=2mm,   tape bend bottom=in and out,
        minimum height=2cm
        ] (block16) { INS\_PLAN\_ACTION  };
        
        
        % Arrows
        
        \draw[blue3 ,-Triangle ,line width=5pt] 
        (block4) edge (block6)
        (block6) edge (block9);
        \draw[blue3 ,-Triangle ,line width=5pt]
        (block9) edge (block10);
        \draw[blue3 ,-Triangle ,line width=5pt] 
        (block10) edge (block11)
        (block11) edge (block12)
        (block12) edge (block19)
        (block19) edge (blockf);
        
        %% brace décoration
        \draw[decorate,gray1,decoration={brace,amplitude=18pt,mirror,raise=4pt},xshift=-4em] (block6.west)--(block9.west)node[midway,left,xshift=-4em]{};
        \draw[decorate,gray1,decoration={brace,amplitude=22pt,mirror,raise=4pt},xshift=-4em] (block11.west)--(blockf.west)node[midway,left,xshift=-4em]{};
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this answer or should be moved to question (replaced existing one)?

Comment: @Zarko Seeing as the answer states "this is the final code", I assume this is an answer.

Comment: @MASSAL: the code in this answer generates three errors (see the .log file, if your editor doesn't show them). You should never ignore errors, but fix them as they occur. The first one is an "option clash" error because you load `inputenc` twice, with different options. You should only have one of those, corresponding to the encoding of your `.tex` file. The two other errors are "I do not know the key"-errors from TikZ, because you've used `maximum width` in two places, and as mentioned above there is no such key. Either change to `minimum width` if that was what you wanted, or delete them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., than mine is not needed anymore ;-)

Comment: @TorbjørnT yeh i didn't pay attention to the three errors i modified the answer thank you so much.

Comment: @Zarko thank you very much your code is clearer than mine .

Comment: On this site is police, that people thankfulness express by upvoting answer and even accepting it (clicking in up triangle and/or on check mark at top left side of answer). As I see, so far you not accept any of answer on you question. Ase anyone of them is not worth for this recognition? To my opinion, your answer is more seems to be part of question than answer. It contain information which are missed in question.

Comment: @zarko Well, sorry, I don't know how the website works also that I find it difficult to express my question since I only use a translator from my native language to English , any way thank u so much

Comment: @MASSAL Then you should [take a tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site.