# coding the arrows in flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to draw the arrow from A-7  (diamond 1 ) to A-4

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=1.27cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Required packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    calc, chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
    positioning,
    shapes}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
\definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
\definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}

\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \small
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
            start chain = A going below,
            arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=3mm, width=6mm]}, line width= 2mm,
                draw=blue2, shorten > = 1mm, shorten <=1mm},
            BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
                decorate,
                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                    pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                    post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                    raise=#1,
                    #2},% for mirroring of brace
                very thick,
                pen colour={#3} },
            N/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                fill=#1,draw=blue2,
                minimum height=10mm, text width=80mm,
                align=flush center},
            N1/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                fill=#1,
                minimum height=10mm, text width=50mm,
                align=flush center},
            N2/.style={draw,text width=3cm ,text centered,
                minimum width=4cm,fill=yellow1,tape, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=1.1mm,   tape bend bottom=in and out,
                minimum height=1.1cm}  ,
            N3/.style = {diamond,   minimum width=7.5cm, minimum height=4mm, text centered, draw=blue2, fill=blue2},
            N4/.style = {rectangle, text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered ,fill=gray2}]
            % main branch
            \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
                \node [N1=blue1,draw=blue1]     {ETAPES};                   % A-1
                \node [N=blue2]   {Besoin en RH};    % A-2
                \node [N=blue2]     {Identification des compétences nécessaires};
                \node [N=blue2]     {Rédaction de l’offre d’emploi};
                \node [N=blue2]     {  Pré-sélection des candidats};
                \node [N=blue2]     {Entretien « final »};
                \node  [N3=blue2] {Candidature validée?};
                \node [N=blue2]     { Préparation, signature et archivage des documents légaux};
                \node [N=blue2]     {Formation interne et enregistrement de la formation };
                \node  [N3=blue2] {Candidature validée?};
                \node [N=blue2]     {Prise de fonction};
            \end{scope}
            
            % nodes on the left side of the main branch
            
            \node [N1=gray1,draw=gray1, 
            left=19 mm of A-1]     (B-1)   {ACTEURS};
            \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2, 
            left=of A-2]     (B-2)   {Collaborateur };
            \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2, 
            left=of A-3]     (B-3)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR };
            \coordinate (aux1) at ($(A-4.south west)!0.5!(A-5.north west)$);
            \draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray2]   (A-4.west) -- (A-5.west);
            \node [N4=gray2,left=of aux1,draw=gray2 ]     (B-4)   { Agence Interim /  Cabinet de recrutement };
            \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
            left=of A-6]     (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR };
            \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
            left=of A-8]     (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR };
            \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
            left=of A-9]     (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR };
            \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
            left=of A-11]     (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR };
            
            % nodes on the right side of thr main branch
            \begin{scope}[N/.append style={text width=44mm},
                N/.default=yellow1]
                \node[N1=yellow1,draw=yellow1,  right=18mm of A-1]     (C-1)   {DOCUMENTS};
                \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-9,text width=5.4cm ]     (C-2)   {FOR\_MATRICE\_COMPETENCES +
                    BDD\_DOCS\_RH };
                \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-11]     (C-3)   {FOR\_FORMATION + BDD\_FORMATIONS};
                
            \end{scope}
            %arrows 
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable. It contain mes of style options and missing style definition., so it is not possible to provide MWE, which solve your problem. Anyway, solution is something like this `\draw (<decision coordinate.east>) -- ++ (1cm, 0) |- ((<target coordinate>)`.

Comment: can you please explain to me why my code is not compilable , because i checked it and it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640857/how-to-draw-flowchart-in-latex/640874#640874) on your previous question
- I would not use white text, fill color of nodes is not sufficient dark that it can be easy to read
- code lines for arrows, which are your problem, are in code marked by `<---`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.27cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}

% Required packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning,
                shapes}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
\definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
\definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}

\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 19mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=3mm, width=6mm]}, line width= 2mm,
                 draw=blue2, shorten > = 1mm, shorten <=1mm},
  base/.style = {draw, thick, minimum height=12mm, 
                 text width=34mm, inner xsep=3pt, font=\small,
                 align=flush center},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour={#3} },
     D/.style = {base, fill=#1, text width=33mm,
                 diamond, aspect=2, inner xsep=-0pt,
                 base},             
     M/.style = {base, fill=#1,
                 tape, tape bend top=none,
                 tape bend height=2mm, tape bend bottom=in and out},
     M/.default=yellow1,
     N/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=#1},
     N/.default=blue2,
                        ]
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr},
                  D/.default=blue2]
\node [N=blue1,
       font=\bfseries]  {ETAPES};                   % A-1
\node [N]   {Besoin en RH};                          
\node [N]   {Identification des compétences nécessaires};
\node [N]   {Rédaction de l’offre d’emploi};
\node [N]   {Pré-sélection des candidats};
\node [N]   {Entretien « final »};
%
\node  [D] {Candidature validée?};                  % A-7
%
\node [N]   {Préparation, signature et archivage des documents légaux};
\node [N]   {Formation interne et enregistrement de la formation};
%
\node [D] {Candidature validée?};                   % A-10
\node [N]     {Prise de fonction};
    \end{scope}
% loop arrows 
\draw[arr]    (A-7.east)  -- ++ (0.8,0) |- (A-4);   % <---
\draw[arr]    (A-10.east) -- ++ (0.8,0) |- (A-9);   % <---
% nodes on the left side of the main branch
\node [N=gray1, 
       left=of A-1]     (B-1)   {ACTEURS};
    \begin{scope}[sharp corners, N/.default=gray2]
\node [N, left=of A-2]  (B-2)   {Collaborateur };
\node [N, left=of A-3]  (B-3)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR };
    \coordinate (aux1) at ($(A-4.south west)!0.5!(A-5.north west)$);
    \draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray]   (A-4.west) -- (A-5.west);
\node [N, left=of aux1] (B-4)   {Agence Interim /  Cabinet de recrutement };
\node [N, left=of A-6]  (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR};
\node [N, left=of A-8]  (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR};
\node [N, left=of A-9]  (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR};
\node [N, left=of A-11] (B-4)   {Directeur et RQ\&AR};
    \end{scope}
% nodes on the right side of thr main branch
\node [N=yellow1,
       right=of A-1]        (C-1)   {DOCUMENTS};
\node [M, text width=55mm,
       at={(C-1 |- A-8)}]   (C-2)   {FOR\_MATRICE\_COMPETENCES +
                                     BDD\_DOCS\_RH };
\node [M, right=of A-9]     (C-3)   {FOR\_FORMATION + BDD\_FORMATIONS};
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]